# Replacing Smoothie Charts with Cubism, or, feeding realtime chart with pubsub data

Tags: javascript, charts, publish-subscribe, cubism.js

So I have `Faye` set up on node.js doing pubsub type stuff for a time-series chart.  With `Smoothie Charts` it looks like this:

```
//set up faye subscription
var subscription = client.subscribe('/myfeed', function(message) {
    //add data to appropriate series
    mySeries.append(new Date(),message.value);
});
```

That's pretty much it.  Now I'm trying to replace smoothie with [Cubism.js](https://square.github.io/cubism/).  Here is an example of pushing a single value that I have working:

```
// create context and horizon
var context = cubism.context().size(960);
var horizon = context.horizon().extent([0,2]);

function testFeed(name) {
    return context.metric(function(start,stop,step,callback){
        var values = [];
        //static value I added
        values.push(85);
        //original random example
        //while (+start < +stop){ start = +start +step; values.push(Math.random());}
        callback(null, values);
    }, name);
}

// draw graph
var metrics = ["Metric1","Metric2","Metric3"];
horizon.metric(testFeed);
```

Sadly I have no idea what most of this means.  So 2 things:

1. How do I integrate my subscription into the feed?
2. How do I send individual values to each "metric"?  Right now that 85 shows up on all 3 metrics.

[image]

I tried the following and I get my data logged to the console but nothing appears on the chart:

```
function testFeed(name) {
    return context.metric(function(start,stop,step,callback){
        var values = [];
        var subscription = client.subscribe('/myfeed', function(message) {
            values.push(message.messageCount);
            console.log(message.messageCount);
        });
        callback(null, values);
    }, name);
}
```

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: cubism is based on d3.js so I thought the tag was appropriate...

Comment: No worries, I removed it because you need knowledge of cubism for this question -- knowing just D3 won't help.

Comment: tags are cumulative though?  With that logic you should have removed everything except `cubism.js`.  On top of that, are you sure that the solution isn't cubism agnostic?

Comment: Well feel free to re-add the tag, but I know D3 quite a bit and have no idea how to solve your problem :)

Comment: heh, just curious.  I always screw up tag etiquette.  :)